# How to get the current file path in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

can i get the full path of my html page through javascript eg My Index page is at

```
         d:/somefolder/anotherfolder/index.html
```

so can i get this path

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You can only access your current file path relative to your host URL, you cannot access the folder path of that file.

This is restricted in JavaScript due to security reasons. If that was allowed, malicious scripts could easily read your server's internal folder structures, which is bad.

Comment: Ya I know we can get the url host path by location.href or location.pathname but i dont want that http:// I want d:/

Comment: @shoaib: No, you _cannot_ do that in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

On a Local Machine it is not possible, however you could use:

```
document.location.href;
```

to get the URL, where your file is hosted

Answer (score 0):

no you can't browser don't allow javascript to access the file paths due to security reasons