# Selenium ide to locate a file and store its path info from any computer

Tags: html, macos, selenium-ide, filepath

currently in my test scripts for automated file upload to browser, the paths are already defined in the value column

command type

target //input[@type='file']

value /Users/.../.../.../filename.extension

in such cases, this script is unable to run on other computers because the path would be different.
my question will be is

1. is there a way to locate the file in a general folder (for example file is downloaded and in the "download" folder), by using selenium ide can we get the path of the file (/Users/.../downloads/filename.extension)
2. store the path of the file with its extension into a notepad which i will be using it for multiple test of file uploads later on.

right now if my colleague needs to run the script from his computer, he have to manually change the value to his path.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a suite file that contains a "setup" file to only change the file name in 1 place and the variable is shared across tests in the suite. You could also select an agreed up on place to store the files: c:\test_info\image.jpg.
Or you can make the file available by URL & not local, Unfortunately javascript prevents that for security: [How to get the current file path in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18612460/how-to-get-the-current-file-path-in-javascript)

Unfortunately I can't think of any other good way unless you all have the same path in a home directory and could do something like ~/test_dir/photo.jpg