# how to dynamically set local file path

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am updating the image uploader for my CMS; loading images with matching thumbnails. The current setup has paired type='file' inputs loading: someImage.jpg + tn_someImage.jpg. I considered using HTML5:

```
<input type="file" name="filefield" multiple="multiple">
```

but this probably still presents browser support issues.

I would like to halve the clicking & file locating by auto-testing if the thumb-pair is present in the same folder. This requires knowing the local folder location. I dynamically create the 'file' inputs

```
$(document).on('change','#filesUp',function(){ // numbered select input
for (i=1; i<=parseInt($('#filesUp').val()); i++) {
$('#filesToUpload').append('<input class="uploadDir" type="file" name="filesToUpload[]" /><P>'); }
});
```

and would like to test, when each file is loaded, if there is an accompanying thumbnails in the same dir. I really want to avoid having the user required to do a double upload.
I tried:

```
$(document).on('change','.uploadDir',function(){
alert(document.location.href); // $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] - in PHP
alert(document.location.pathname); // $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]
});
```

but this just gives the path of the executing file.
Several answers to "find local path" - eg: 
[How to get the current file path in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18612460/how-to-get-the-current-file-path-in-javascript)
say: "This is restricted in JavaScript [hence jQuery] due to security reasons. If that was allowed, malicious scripts could easily read your server's internal folder structures, which is bad."

Quite right - but... there must be *some* client-side one-click way to load the directory path - short of having the user type it in. Maybe not??

I am coding in PHP, js / jQ and would prefer not to use plugins or java.

Comment: currently exploring just assuming thumbs are there and checking with $_FILES['userfile']['error'] and the option to auto create missing thumbs. Direct error indication would be better but... Maybe not possible?

Comment: I needed to do something similar once and came to the conclusion that browsers' security constraints didn't allow it. A workaround for you would be to upload only the full-size images and generate thumbnails from them server-side.

Comment: @Roamer - thanks for the feedback/confirmation. What did *you* end up doing? I am assuming that thumbs will be available so need to test for their absence.

Comment: Arfa, it was so long ago, I can't remember the precise scenario or even which project I was working on. It's all very hazy.

Comment: @Roamer - I know the feeling, even from just a week ago  :) I am looking at $_FILES[] and figure a way will be found. not sure how to mark this as CLOSED. thx

Comment: Since you don't have a proper answer, I would leave it open. Someone more knowledgeable may come up with something yet. Good luck.